# Android Studio on SSD drive

Tags: android-studio, sdk

I just have a SSD drive which is 240 GB. I also have a mechanic drive which is 1 TB.

Im gonna install Android Studio to SSD.

The question is should i install SDK too on SSD ?

is it gonna improve Android Studio performance ?

Comment: Of course. My tests give about 25x (2500%) faster.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try

Comment: what is the size of android studio in SSD as i am buying 120GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure will improve the performance , however marginally , you wouldn't feel much difference ...

Comment: Thanks for response. I decided to install SDK and others to mechanic drive. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Machine Specs: Alienware-i7 7820HK|16GB RAM|256GB PCie SSD|1TB HDD

Software Config: Android Studio in SSD|SDK in HDD|Project Folder in HDD

- Clock Time to load Android Studio: 9s
- Clock Time to create a new empty project: 20s till Gradle Build Finished
- Clock Time to open an empty project: Less than 5s till Gradle Build Finished
- Clock Time to open Android Studio; create a new empty project: 40s till Gradle Build Finished

Comment: Thanks for sharing this valuable infos. Seems helpful